# How to use any obtained variable from a function in other functions in Python classes?

Tags: python, class, oop, ip

I am trying to use one variable obtained from one function in other function. However , it gives error. Let me explain it wih my code.

```
class Uygulama(object):
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.araclar()
        self.refresh()
        self.gateway_find()
    def refresh(self):
    
    self.a, self.b = srp(Ether(dst="FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF") / ARP(pdst=self.ip_range2), timeout=2,     iface="eth0",
               retry=3)

     #There are unrelated codes here

    def gateway_find(self):
    
    #Find ip any range in which you conncet:
    self.ip_range=conf.route.route("0.0.0.0")[1]
    self.ip_range1=self.ip_range.rpartition(".")[0]
    self.ip_range2=self.iprange_1+".0/24"
```

When , run the foregoing codes , i get this error **AttributeError: 'Uygulama' object has no attribute 'ip_range2'**

How can i use such variable which are obtained from other function in the other function. How can i fix my problem ?

Comment: Your indentation seems off. This may have happened while pasting the code here or it may be the source of the problem.

Comment: Hi Ulahh, I think the indentation of the code snippet you provided doesn't reflect your actual code. Maybe edit the question to improve it.
Also, the title would be better like this: "How to access attribute define in other methods of a class?" Remove "python", it's already in the tags :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Call order of init functions

### Place function that define attribute first

In the `__init__` function, you call refresh, who use (need) `ip_range2` before `gateway_find` who create the attribute and set a value to it. Swap the two lines, you should be fine.

```py
    def __init__(self):
        self.araclar()
        self.gateway_find()  # gateway_find will set the ip_range attribute
        self.refresh()  # So refresh function will be able to access it
```

Usually, we place init functions first, then function that will call post-init processes like `refresh`.

## Class attribute default value

Alternatively, you can define a default value for `ip_range2` like this:

```py
class Uygulama(object):
    ip_range2 = None

    def __init__(self):
        self.araclar()
        self.refresh()
        self.gateway_find()

    def refresh(self):
        self.a, self.b = srp(Ether(dst="FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF") / ARP(pdst=self.ip_range2), timeout=2, iface="eth0", retry=3)
```

Be aware that such default value is shared with all other instances of the class if not redefined in `__init__`, so if it's a mutable (like a list), it might create really weird bugs.

Usually, prefer defining value in the `__init__` like you do with the gateway fct.

Answer (score 0):

That error explains correctly that you do not have a class attribute called `ip_range2`. You need to define the class attribute first.

```
class Uygulama(object):
    ip_range2 = ''
    ...
```

then use that with `self.ip_range2`.